# I can't make this container css - html

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a container like this website mvmtwatches.com, the container is the first one, "men watches".

I'm using code from my theme of prestashop but i can't figure out how to get the same container.

```
        <div class="homebanner-content">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="wrapper-content"><img class="img-responsive" src="..img/cms/bands.jpg" alt="Bandas homepage categoria" href="../band/"/><a href="../band/" title="Bandas"><span>Correas Intercambiables</span></a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help to get a container exactly like that one please?

thank you

Comment: by the way, you do not need to use all of the column classes if all breakpoints are going to have the same 12 column size.  You can just omit the column classes altogether, or just define the xs class since it will cascade upwards due to the way bootstrap is set up.

Comment: yes, i did'nt realized about the column class. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using Bootstrap. So just use its grid system. Placing each `.wrapper-content` inside a `col-sm-6` will create the layout you want when page width is above 767px. On smaller devices they will display one below the other.

I added a bit of CSS to position the text as in your example.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One');
.homebanner-content {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.homebanner-content .row {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.homebanner-content .wrapper-content {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px -10px;
}
.homebanner-content .img-responsive {
  width: 100%;
}

.homebanner-content .wrapper-content > a {
  font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 4rem;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .homebanner-content .wrapper-content > a {
    text-align: center;
    white-space: normal;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="homebanner-content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="wrapper-content">
        <img class="img-responsive" 
             src="https://unsplash.it/785/630/?blur" 
             alt="Bandas homepage categoria" />
        <a href="../band" title="Bandas">
          <span>Correas Intercambiables</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="wrapper-content">
        <img class="img-responsive" 
             src="https://unsplash.it/g/785/630/?blur" 
             alt="Bandas homepage categoria" />
        <a href="../band/" title="Bandas">
          <span>Correas Intercambiables</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Andrei. Your code helped me a lot. I mixed with other answer and i get what i need. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

How does this look?  Check out this link: https://jsfiddle.net/j4cd9awv/

HTML

```
<section class="home-tile-container home-tile-container-a">

  <div class="home-tile-half home-tile-1">
    <a href="/collections/all-mens-watches">
        <div class="hover-overlay"></div>
        <div class="cta-content">
            <h3 class="white"><span>mens watches</span></h3>
            <button class="button button--white">shop now</button>
        </div>
    </a>
  </div> 
</section>
```

CSS

```
a, a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: auto;
}

.home-tile-container-a .home-tile-half:first-child {
    border-left: solid 10px #fff;
    border-right: solid 5px #fff;
}

.home-tile-container-a .home-tile-half.home-tile-1 {
    background-image: url(//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0377/2037/t/37/assets/collection-img-1_920x.jpg?1052957349189286585);
}

.home-tile-container-a .home-tile-half {
    min-height: 650px;
}

.home-tile-container-a .home-tile-half {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: end;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
    -ms-flex-align: end;
    align-items: flex-end;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-position: center !important;
    border-top: solid 10px #fff;
    min-height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
    transition: all 0.25s;
}

.hover-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
    transition: all 0.25s;
}

.home-tile-container-a .cta-content {
    padding: 15px 15px 80px;
}

.home-tile-container-a .cta-content {
    padding: 15px 15px 30px;
}

.cta-content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    text-align: center;
}

.home-tile-container-a .cta-content h3.white {
    color: #fff;
}

.home-tile-container-a .cta-content h3 {
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.6px;
    line-height: 1.25;
    color: #2c2c2c;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.home-tile-container-a .cta-content h3 span {
    font-size: 59px;
}

.home-tile-container-a .cta-content h3 span {
    display: block;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0.4px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button.button--white, .livechat_button a.button--white, #storemapper-go.button--white {
    background: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "Gotham-Bold";
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #2c2c2c;
}

.button, .livechat_button a, #storemapper-go {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 1rem .50rem;
    border-radius: 1px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    font-family: "Gotham-Bold";
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
    transition: all 0.25s;
    position: relative;
}

button {
    cursor: pointer;
}

button {
    color: inherit;
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Dont forget to upvote and select the correct answer!

Answer (score -1):

In Bootstrap you do not need to apply multiple grid classes to one element. If you are trying to mirror the site you have listed then each child in the parent container should use the class `col-lg-6`, as there are two items and the breakpoints are quite large.

Bootstrap uses a grid layout where elements must add up to 12, so I would suggest something like:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="..img/cms/bands.jpg" alt="Bandas homepage categoria" href="../band/"/>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="..img/cms/bands.jpg" alt="Bandas homepage categoria" href="../band/"/>
</div>
```